# probability of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, random

We're going to look at a random process, which is a sequence of random variables that depends on time.

Let $X(t)$ = $A/t$ where A has the density $f_A(a)$ = $3/8$ $a^2$ for $ 0<=a <= 2$. Assume $t > 0$.

a)Find $F_X(x)$ and $f_X(x)$ (to get this, assume t is fixed-so you can assume t is a constant).

b) Find $E(X)$

So for part a, I know $F_X(x)$ = $P(X <= x)$. So this is rewritten as $P(A <= tx)$. So its the integral from $0$ to $tx$ of $3/8$ $a^2$, which is $ 1/8$ $a^3$ but I'm confused on if I'm supposed to plug values in for $tx$ and solve or just leave it as is. Then do I take the first derivative of $1/8$ $a^3$ to find $f_X(x)$?

Also not sure how to find $E(X)$ since I have to include x in the integral, but my function is in terms of a.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** You are on the right track.

$$ F_X(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(A \leq xt), $$

leading to

$$ P(A \leq xt) = \int_{-\infty}^{xt} \frac{3}{8} a^2 da = \int_{0}^{xt} \frac{3}{8} a^2 da = \frac{1}{8} a^3 |_0^{tx} = \frac{1}{8} t^3 x^3  $$

And then yes, the [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function (with respect to $x$!).

**b)** Your probability density function is in terms of $x$, so it should be straight forward to find $E(X)$ now.

$$ E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f_X(x)dx = \int_0^{2/t}x f_X(x)dx $$

Comment: Do I have to plug in values for t or x when giving the answer for $F_X(x)$ and $f_X(x)$ ? Also, How do I find $E(X)$ if there is still a $t^3$ in the equation?

Comment: No, you should not plug in values for $t$ or $x$. t is treated as a constant (which you don't know), and $x$ is your variable. One thing you might have to think about, though, is normalising the solution so that the probability density function is valid: $\int_{\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)dx=1$

Comment: So for that can I just include the interval $ 0 \leq x \leq 2/t$ in my answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you meant, but when you evaluate the interval between $0$ and $2/t$, it should be equal to 1. I checked, and it is.. you can disregard my comment about it, I just wasn't sure if there was a need for normalisation.

Comment: Right. My only other question is to find $E(X)$, I have to integrate $\int \frac{1}{8} t^3x^3$ correct? Do I pull the $t^3$ out of the integral? and what range do I integrate over?

Comment: I put the formula for $E(X)$ in the answer. Be careful to integrate over the density function $f_X(x)$ (multiplied by $x$, of course, because you're looking for the expected value), not the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$. It doesn't matter if you pull $t^3$ out of the integral, since it's just a constant anyway.. you integrate over $x$.

Comment: So its not possible to get an actual numerical answer for $E(X)$, right? since we will always have t so the answer will be in terms of t

Comment: Right, your result will always be in terms of $t$ - until you're evaluating the expected value at a certain time point. Then you can just plug in the desired value for $t$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10923/discussion-between-lisa-and-no-name)